# Adding Zend code intelligence for Komodo

Tags: php, zend-framework, gecko, komodo, code-intelligence

How can I add code intelligence for Zend library in Komodo?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is an add-on for this that was included with Komodo Edit 5.x by default. The [source](https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit/tree/master/src/modules/zendframework) can be downloaded and packaged into an XPI using the following commands:

```
git clone https://github.com/Komodo/KomodoEdit/tree/master/src/modules/zendframework zendframework

cd zendframework

zip -Dr zendframework.jar content skin raw pylib project-templates test
zip -Dr zendframework.xpi zendframework.jar install.rdf chrome.manifest
```